# Combine geom_tile() and facet_grid/facet_wrap and remove space between tiles (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tile, facet

I have a data set with x, y, and z (`resp`) values along with two columns for facetting in order to create a grid of tile plots.

The output of `dput()` is at the end of the post.

```
library(ggplot2)
```

My actual data set has six unique interactions between variables, however I've limited it to four for simplicity. I can create a tile plot with each unique combination, but not the whole set. The output of `dput()` is at the end of the post. I thought it might have to do with `ggplot` needing a common y axis scale, but that's not the issue.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data_sub, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = resp))
p <- p + facet_wrap(var2 ~ var1, scales = "free", ncol = 2)
```

The output:

[image: tile plot with white space]

Plotted on their own, there is no such white space:

```
x1x2 <- data_sub[data_sub$var1 == "x1" & data_sub$var2 == "x3", ]
ggplot(x1x2, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = resp))
```

[image: filled in single tile plot]

I believe the issue is defining some sort of dynamic `height` and `width` aesthetic in the `geom_tile()` call, but I'm not sure how to do this. It seems that a single tile plot will use something like `diff((unique(x))` to come up with the appropriate height, but I'm not sure how to do that for each facet level -- is the only way to create such columns in my data frame?

---

The data:

```
dput(data_sub)
structure(list(x = c(-3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, -3, -2.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 
0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 
0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 
0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 
1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 
0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 
0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 
0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 
0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 
0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 
1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 
0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 
0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 
0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 
0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 
0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 
1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 
0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 
0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 
0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 
0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 
0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 
1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 
0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 
0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 
0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 
0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 
0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 
1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 
0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 
0.888888888888889, 1), y = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6.66666666666667, 
6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 
6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 
6.66666666666667, 8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 
8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 
8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 
11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 
11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 
13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 
13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 
13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 
16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 
16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 18.3333333333333, 
18.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 
18.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 
18.3333333333333, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 
0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 
0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 
1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 
1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 
1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 
2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 
2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 
3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 
3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 
3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 
3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 
3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 
4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 
5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 
5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 
6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 
6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 
6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 
6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 
6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 
8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 
8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 
8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 
11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 
11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 13.3333333333333, 
13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 
13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 
13.3333333333333, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16.6666666666667, 
16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 
16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 
16.6666666666667, 18.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 
18.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 
18.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 
0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 
0.777777777777778, 0.777777777777778, 1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 
1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 
1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 1.55555555555556, 
2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 
2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 
2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 
3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 
3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 3.11111111111111, 
3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 
3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 
3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 
5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 
5.44444444444444, 5.44444444444444, 6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 
6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 
6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 6.22222222222222, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), var1 = c("x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", 
"x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2"
), var2 = c("x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", 
"x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", 
"x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x4"), resp = c(49.855790574209, 
51.1750882867235, 52.494385999238, 53.8136837117525, 55.132981424267, 
56.4522791367815, 57.771576849296, 59.0908745618105, 60.410172274325, 
61.7294699868395, 56.5060300788685, 57.825327791383, 59.1446255038975, 
60.463923216412, 61.7832209289265, 63.102518641441, 64.4218163539555, 
65.74111406647, 67.0604117789845, 68.379709491499, 63.1562695835279, 
64.4755672960424, 65.7948650085569, 67.1141627210714, 68.4334604335859, 
69.7527581461004, 71.0720558586149, 72.3913535711294, 73.7106512836439, 
75.0299489961584, 69.8065090881873, 71.1258068007018, 72.4451045132163, 
73.7644022257308, 75.0836999382454, 76.4029976507599, 77.7222953632744, 
79.0415930757889, 80.3608907883034, 81.6801885008178, 76.4567485928468, 
77.7760463053613, 79.0953440178758, 80.4146417303903, 81.7339394429048, 
83.0532371554193, 84.3725348679338, 85.6918325804483, 87.0111302929628, 
88.3304280054773, 83.1069880975062, 84.4262858100207, 85.7455835225352, 
87.0648812350497, 88.3841789475642, 89.7034766600787, 91.0227743725932, 
92.3420720851077, 93.6613697976222, 94.9806675101367, 89.7572276021656, 
91.0765253146801, 92.3958230271947, 93.7151207397092, 95.0344184522237, 
96.3537161647382, 97.6730138772527, 98.9923115897672, 100.311609302282, 
101.630907014796, 96.4074671068251, 97.7267648193396, 99.0460625318541, 
100.365360244369, 101.684657956883, 103.003955669398, 104.323253381912, 
105.642551094427, 106.961848806941, 108.281146519456, 103.057706611485, 
104.377004323999, 105.696302036514, 107.015599749028, 108.334897461543, 
109.654195174057, 110.973492886572, 112.292790599086, 113.612088311601, 
114.931386024115, 109.707946116144, 111.027243828658, 112.346541541173, 
113.665839253687, 114.985136966202, 116.304434678716, 117.623732391231, 
118.943030103745, 120.26232781626, 121.581625528774, 44.8527240775983, 
46.1720217901128, 47.4913195026273, 48.8106172151418, 50.1299149276563, 
51.4492126401708, 52.7685103526853, 54.0878080651998, 55.4071057777143, 
56.7264034902288, 48.7344239681344, 50.0537216806489, 51.3730193931634, 
52.6923171056779, 54.0116148181924, 55.3309125307069, 56.6502102432214, 
57.9695079557359, 59.2888056682504, 60.6081033807649, 52.6161238586705, 
53.935421571185, 55.2547192836995, 56.574016996214, 57.8933147087285, 
59.212612421243, 60.5319101337575, 61.851207846272, 63.1705055587865, 
64.489803271301, 56.4978237492065, 57.817121461721, 59.1364191742355, 
60.45571688675, 61.7750145992646, 63.094312311779, 64.4136100242935, 
65.732907736808, 67.0522054493226, 68.3715031618371, 60.3795236397426, 
61.6988213522571, 63.0181190647716, 64.3374167772861, 65.6567144898006, 
66.9760122023151, 68.2953099148296, 69.6146076273441, 70.9339053398586, 
72.2532030523731, 64.2612235302787, 65.5805212427932, 66.8998189553077, 
68.2191166678222, 69.5384143803367, 70.8577120928512, 72.1770098053657, 
73.4963075178802, 74.8156052303947, 76.1349029429092, 68.1429234208147, 
69.4622211333293, 70.7815188458437, 72.1008165583582, 73.4201142708727, 
74.7394119833872, 76.0587096959017, 77.3780074084163, 78.6973051209308, 
80.0166028334453, 72.0246233113508, 73.3439210238653, 74.6632187363798, 
75.9825164488943, 77.3018141614088, 78.6211118739233, 79.9404095864378, 
81.2597072989523, 82.5790050114668, 83.8983027239813, 75.9063232018869, 
77.2256209144014, 78.5449186269159, 79.8642163394304, 81.1835140519449, 
82.5028117644594, 83.8221094769739, 85.1414071894884, 86.4607049020029, 
87.7800026145174, 79.7880230924229, 81.1073208049374, 82.4266185174519, 
83.7459162299664, 85.065213942481, 86.3845116549954, 87.7038093675099, 
89.0231070800245, 90.342404792539, 91.6617025050535, 55.0389923581682, 
55.076209045692, 55.1878591082632, 55.373942545882, 55.6344593585483, 
55.9694095462621, 56.3787931090235, 56.8626100468323, 57.4208603596887, 
58.0535440475926, 61.6892318628276, 61.7264485503514, 61.8380986129227, 
62.0241820505415, 62.2846988632078, 62.6196490509216, 63.0290326136829, 
63.5128495514918, 64.0710998643481, 64.703783552252, 68.3394713674871, 
68.3766880550108, 68.4883381175821, 68.6744215552009, 68.9349383678672, 
69.269888555581, 69.6792721183423, 70.1630890561512, 70.7213393690076, 
71.3540230569114, 74.9897108721465, 75.0269275596703, 75.1385776222415, 
75.3246610598603, 75.5851778725266, 75.9201280602404, 76.3295116230018, 
76.8133285608106, 77.371578873667, 78.0042625615709, 81.639950376806, 
81.6771670643297, 81.788817126901, 81.9749005645198, 82.2354173771861, 
82.5703675648999, 82.9797511276612, 83.4635680654701, 84.0218183783264, 
84.6545020662303, 88.2901898814654, 88.3274065689891, 88.4390566315604, 
88.6251400691792, 88.8856568818455, 89.2206070695593, 89.6299906323207, 
90.1138075701295, 90.6720578829859, 91.3047415708897, 94.9404293861248, 
94.9776460736486, 95.0892961362198, 95.2753795738386, 95.5358963865049, 
95.8708465742187, 96.2802301369801, 96.7640470747889, 97.3222973876453, 
97.9549810755492, 101.590668890784, 101.627885578308, 101.739535640879, 
101.925619078498, 102.186135891164, 102.521086078878, 102.93046964164, 
103.414286579448, 103.972536892305, 104.605220580209, 108.240908395444, 
108.278125082967, 108.389775145539, 108.575858583158, 108.836375395824, 
109.171325583538, 109.580709146299, 110.064526084108, 110.622776396964, 
111.255460084868, 114.891147900103, 114.928364587627, 115.040014650198, 
115.226098087817, 115.486614900483, 115.821565088197, 116.230948650958, 
116.714765588767, 117.273015901624, 117.905699589528, 50.0359258615575, 
50.0731425490813, 50.1847926116525, 50.3708760492713, 50.6313928619376, 
50.9663430496514, 51.3757266124128, 51.8595435502216, 52.417793863078, 
53.0504775509819, 53.9176257520936, 53.9548424396173, 54.0664925021886, 
54.2525759398074, 54.5130927524737, 54.8480429401875, 55.2574265029488, 
55.7412434407577, 56.2994937536141, 56.9321774415179, 57.7993256426296, 
57.8365423301534, 57.9481923927247, 58.1342758303435, 58.3947926430098, 
58.7297428307236, 59.1391263934849, 59.6229433312938, 60.1811936441501, 
60.813877332054, 61.6810255331657, 61.7182422206895, 61.8298922832607, 
62.0159757208795, 62.2764925335458, 62.6114427212596, 63.020826284021, 
63.5046432218298, 64.0628935346862, 64.6955772225901, 65.5627254237018, 
65.5999421112255, 65.7115921737968, 65.8976756114156, 66.1581924240819, 
66.4931426117957, 66.9025261745571, 67.3863431123659, 67.9445934252223, 
68.5772771131261, 69.4444253142378, 69.4816420017616, 69.5932920643329, 
69.7793755019516, 70.039892314618, 70.3748425023318, 70.7842260650931, 
71.268043002902, 71.8262933157583, 72.4589770036622, 73.3261252047739, 
73.3633418922977, 73.4749919548689, 73.6610753924877, 73.921592205154, 
74.2565423928679, 74.6659259556292, 75.149742893438, 75.7079932062944, 
76.3406768941983, 77.20782509531, 77.2450417828337, 77.356691845405, 
77.5427752830238, 77.8032920956901, 78.1382422834039, 78.5476258461653, 
79.0314427839741, 79.5896930968305, 80.2223767847343, 81.089524985846, 
81.1267416733698, 81.2383917359411, 81.4244751735599, 81.6849919862262, 
82.01994217394, 82.4293257367013, 82.9131426745102, 83.4713929873665, 
84.1040766752704, 84.9712248763821, 85.0084415639059, 85.1200916264771, 
85.3061750640959, 85.5666918767622, 85.9016420644761, 86.3110256272374, 
86.7948425650462, 87.3530928779026, 87.9857765658065)), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "var1", "var2", "resp"), row.names = 101:500, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It [works for me](http://i.imgur.com/e8WbRM6.png). What version of R and ggplot2 are you using?

Comment: It may help to convert `var1` and `var2` to factors.

Comment: From `sessionInfo`: R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16), ggplot2_0.9.3.1. (In  RStudio 0.97.551). I tried `data_sub$var1 <- factor(data_sub$var1, levels = unique(data_sub$var1))` and the same for `var2` but get the same result.

Comment: Odd. Just tried in a fresh session and it works. I have no idea what got goofed in my session. Any suggestions on getting the tiles to join? (I can update the above to show the current sparse tile map and change the question).

Comment: I'll update this tomorrow when I have more time; I'm generating `data_sub` via the output of `predict(lm, data)`. Oddly, I compared my `predict()` output to a new object created using the `dput` output above and `identical(data_sub, dput_data)` was `FALSE`. I created a third object to store `dput(dput_data)` and it didn't match `dput_data`. Turns out it must be some sort of slight floating point issue. If I rounded each object's `x`, `y`, and `resp` columns, the data frames matched. The non-rounded version creates a blank plot (like above); the rounded version worked. Is that odd?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into two issues:

1) My true data set is generated via `fit <- lm(x ~ y)`, followed by creating a new input data set via `expand.grid`, and then creating my plot data with `predict(fit, newdata)`. Oddly, if I don't round the `x` and `y` points, I can't generate a plot (full code for creating my plot data is below).

2) When plotting one `geom_tile` plot, the height/width of the tiles are set to fill the space. When creating a facetted set of tile plots, it seems that the `height` and `width` arguments for `geom_tile()` default to something else. I'd say they default to the smallest range, but no plot actually fills the full facet window width or height... so it's not that.

Apologies for the example above not being reproducible. I didn't expect that `dput()` wouldn't create an identical data set and it was much simpler to just paste the output of that than have someone run all the code below.

---

Full code for generating the data set:

```
set.seed(42)
x1 <- rnorm(20)
x2 <- runif(20)
x3 <- rpois(20,10)
x4 <- rexp(20)
y <- 10 + 2*x1 + 3*x2^2 + 4*x3 +5*x4 + rnorm(20, sd=0.1)

dat <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, y)

# vector of variable names for easy data.frame column naming later
var_names <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")

# possible combinations of four variables
combis <- combn(1:4, 2)
combis <- rbind(combis, combis[, 6:1])

# steps to generate for the contour using `rep(min, max, length.out = n)`
n <- 100

#fit the model
fit <- lm(y~x1+I(x2^2)+x3+x4, data=dat)

# range values for when variable is featured on an axis
mins_maxs <- data.frame(x1 = c(-3, 3),
                        x2 = c(0, 1),
                        x3 = c(5, 20),
                        x4 = c(0, 7))

# values to hold for plots in which variables are not on an axis
holds <- c(0, 0.5, 10, 5)

sim_data <- list()
sim_data <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(combis)), function (i) {
  sim_data[[i]] <- expand.grid(seq(mins_maxs[1, combis[1, i]], 
                                   mins_maxs[2, combis[1, i]], length.out = n),
                               seq(mins_maxs[1, combis[2, i]], 
                                   mins_maxs[2, combis[2, i]], length.out = n),
                               holds[combis[3, i]],
                               holds[combis[4, i]])
} )

# we create a new data frame for the data set we want to plot
# for each contour of interest, we want the first two columns, as the second two
# were only created for the sake of feeding into our fit lm 
# we'll also create a vector for facetting using paste()
plot_data <- list()
plot_data <- lapply(1:ncol(combis), function(i) {
  plot_data[[i]] <- sim_data[[i]][, 1:2]
  plot_data[[i]]$var1 <- rep(var_names[combis[1, i]],
                             nrow(plot_data[[i]]))
  plot_data[[i]]$var2 <- rep(var_names[combis[2, i]],
                                   nrow(plot_data[[i]]))
  return(plot_data[[i]])
} )

# now we rename the columns of plot_data
plot_data <- lapply(1:length(plot_data), function(i) {
  names(plot_data[[i]]) <- c("x", "y", "var1", "var2")
  return(plot_data[[i]])
} )

# similarly, we need to re-name the sim_data columns so we can rbind them
# and predict new values using our fit lm
sim_data <- lapply(1:length(sim_data), function(i) {
  names(sim_data[[i]]) <- var_names[combis[, i]]
  return(sim_data[[i]])
} )


# collapse the separate lists into one data.frame
plot_data <- do.call(rbind, plot_data)
sim_data <- do.call(rbind, sim_data)

# create a vector of predictions using sim_data
plot_data$resp <- predict(fit, sim_data)
```

---

At this point, if one attempts to plot using `plot_data`, we get this:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = x, y = y, z = resp))
p <- p + geom_tile(aes(fill = resp))
p <- p + facet_wrap(var2 ~ var1, scales = "free", ncol = 3) + theme_bw()
```

[image: data as-is]

If we round the data, we get something else:

```
plot_data_round <- plot_data
plot_data_round[, c("x", "y")] <- round(plot_data_round[, c("x", "y")], 5)

# same plot call as above
p <- ggplot(plot_data_round, aes(x = x, y = y, z = resp))
p <- p + geom_tile(aes(fill = resp))
p <- p + facet_wrap(var2 ~ var1, scales = "free", ncol = 3) + theme_bw()
```

[image: data with rounding]

If we take the un-rounded data and add vectors to store height and width, we're back to a blank facetted plot like the un-rounded data alone.

```
plot_data_hw <- plot_data
hw <- ddply(plot_data, .(var1, var2), summarize,
            height = (max(y) - min(y))/n, width = (max(x) - min(x))/n)
plot_data_hw <- merge(plot_data_hw, hw, by = c("var1", "var2"), all.x = T)
# verify using same plot call and plot_data_hw
```

If we combine rounding *and* `height` and `width` values per facet interaction, we get the desired result (adding `height`/`width` arguments to `geom_tile()`):

```
plot_data_hw_round <- merge(plot_data_round, hw, by = c("var1", "var2"), all.x = T)
p <- ggplot(plot_data_hw_round, aes(x = x, y = y, z = resp))
p <- p + geom_tile(aes(fill = resp, height = height, width = width))
p <- p + facet_wrap(var2 ~ var1, scales = "free", ncol = 3) + theme_bw()
```

[image: facetted tile map as desired]

So, there it is. I'm going to file a bug report about the rounding issue, as that seems quite peculiar to me. Perhaps there's still something going on other than that, but if it is a but due to floating point precision or whatnot, Hadley may still be interested.

Comment: If anyone runs into this and wants to follow along, the [bug report](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/849) has been created at the github project page.

Comment: after nine years, this solution of providing the width and heights, works! Thanks!