# How to plot a matrix of variable interactions

Tags: r, data-visualization

My problem is simple. Suppose I have data with one response variable (y), and three explanatory variables (x1, x2, x3)...

```
# Example data
set.seed(123)
my.data <- data.frame(y = c(seq(1,5,length=20)+rnorm(20)),
                     x1 = c(seq(5,1,length=20)+rnorm(20)),
                     x2 = c(seq(1,10, length=20)+rnorm(20)),
                     x3 = rnorm(20))
```

I make a model. The only interactions in which I am **interested** in are these (**only double interactions**):

```
# Model creation
m1 <- lm(y ~ x1*x2*x3, data = my.data); summary(m1)
# x1:x2       -0.05754    0.06413  -0.897    0.387
# x1:x3       -0.47773    1.18781  -0.402    0.695
# x2:x3       -0.14915    0.48975  -0.305    0.766
```

**I am able to visualize the individual intractions** in desired way (heatmap) by this code but **problem is that always one by one**. For example intraction of "x1:x2"

```
# required packages
library(rms)
library(lattice)

ddI <- datadist(my.data)
options(datadist="ddI")

lininterp <- ols(y ~ x1*x2, data=my.data)

bplot(Predict(lininterp, x1=seq(c(min(my.data$x1)-1), c(max(my.data$x1)+1), length = 20),
                         x2=seq(c(min(my.data$x2)-1), c(max(my.data$x2)+1), length = 20)),
                         col.regions = colorRampPalette(c("red","yellow","darkgreen"))(100))
```

I have more than 3 explanatory variables, so the plotting is quite annoying. **I would like to get something like this plot (below)**, but it is above my R programming skills:

[image]

I did not found any `R package` which can handle it, therefore I appreciate any helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `ggplot` solution. This assumes that the first column of `my.data` has the response, and all the other columns are explanatory variables.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)      # for .(...)

vars <- colnames(my.data)[2:ncol(my.data)]    # explanatory variables
vars <- data.frame(t(expand.grid(vars,vars)))
gg <- do.call(rbind,lapply(vars,function(v){
  v   <- as.character(v)
  fit <- lm(formula(paste("y~",v[1],"*",v[2])),my.data)
  r1  <- range(my.data[v[1]])
  r2  <- range(my.data[v[2]])
  df  <- expand.grid(seq(r1[1],r1[2],length=20),seq(r2[1],r2[2],length=20))
  colnames(df) <- v
  df$pred      <- predict(fit,newdata=df)
  colnames(df) <- c("x","y","pred")
  return(cbind(H=v[1],V=v[2],df))
}))

gg     <- data.frame(gg)                     # ggplot needs a data frame
labels <- aggregate(cbind(x,y)~H+V,gg,mean)  # labels for the diagonals

ggplot(gg)+
  geom_tile(subset=.(as.numeric(H) < as.numeric(V)),aes(x,y,fill=pred),height=1,width=1)+
  geom_text(data=labels, subset=.(H==V),aes(x,y,label=H),size=8)+
  facet_grid(V~H,scales="free")+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=colorRampPalette(c("red","yellow","darkgreen"))(100))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

A couple of notes:

- We have to set `height` and `width` in `geom_tile(...)` or the tiles do not display. *This is a bug in ggplot.* (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157975/combine-geom-tile-and-facet-grid-facet-wrap-and-remove-space-between-tiles-gg)).
- We use `subset=.(as.numeric(H) < as.numeric(V))` to tile only the lower triangular elements.
- We use `data=labels` and `subset=.(H==V)` in `geom_text(...)` to label the diagonal elements.
- We use `expand=c(0,0)` in `scale_x(y)_continuous(...)` to completely fill the panels with tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you started (inspired from answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22996454/903061)).

```
plot1 <- bplot(Predict(lininterp,
               x1=seq(c(min(my.data$x1)-1), c(max(my.data$x1)+1), length = 20),
               x2=seq(c(min(my.data$x2)-1), c(max(my.data$x2)+1), length = 20)),
               col.regions = colorRampPalette(c("red","yellow","darkgreen"))(100))
library(gridExtra)
nullplot <- nullGrob()
grid.arrange(plot1, nullplot, plot1, plot1, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

You can get rid of the legend and plot it separately. If you want things sized differently (like the legend) you may have more luck with `wq::layOut`, as in my answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

I made a function out of @jlhoward's answer:

```
interaction.plot <- function(my.data, response.col, ignore = NULL) {
  vars <- colnames(my.data)[!(colnames(my.data) %in% c(response.col, ignore))]    # explanatory variables
  vars <- data.frame(t(expand.grid(vars,vars)))
  gg <- do.call(rbind,lapply(vars,function(v){
    v   <- as.character(v)
    fit <- lm(formula(paste(response.col,"~",v[1],"*",v[2])),my.data)
    r1  <- range(my.data[v[1]])
    r2  <- range(my.data[v[2]])
    df  <- expand.grid(seq(r1[1],r1[2],length=20),seq(r2[1],r2[2],length=20))
    colnames(df) <- v
    df$pred      <- predict(fit,newdata=df)
    colnames(df) <- c("x","y","pred")
    return(cbind(H=v[1],V=v[2],df))
  }))

  gg     <- data.frame(gg)                     # ggplot needs a data frame
  labels <- aggregate(cbind(x,y)~H+V,gg,mean)  # labels for the diagonals

  ggplot(gg)+
    geom_tile(subset=.(as.numeric(H) < as.numeric(V)),aes(x,y,fill=pred),height=1,width=1)+
    geom_text(data=labels, subset=.(H==V),aes(x,y,label=H),size=8)+
    facet_grid(V~H,scales="free")+
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours=colorRampPalette(c("red","yellow","darkgreen"))(100))+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
}

interaction.plot(data.set, response.col = 'y', ignore = c('age', 'height'))
```