# ggplot2 custom stat not shown when facetting

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I'm trying to write a custom `stat_*` for `ggplot2`, where I would like to color a 2D loess surface using tiles. When I [start from the extension guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html), I can write a stat_chull like they do:

```r
stat_chull = function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "polygon",
                       position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                       inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {

  chull = ggproto("chull", Stat,
    compute_group = function(data, scales) {
      data[chull(data$x, data$y), , drop = FALSE]
    },
    required_aes = c("x", "y")
  )

  layer(
    stat = chull, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}
```

This work for both the simple call and facet wrapping:

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_chull()
# optionally + facet_wrap(~ class)
```

[image: chull without facetting] [image: chull with facetting]

When I write my `stat_loess2d`, I can also visualize all classes or an individual class:

```r
stat_loess2d = function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "tile",
                       position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                       inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {

  loess2d = ggproto("loess2d", Stat,
    compute_group = function(data, scales) {
      dens = MASS::kde2d(data$x, data$y)
      lsurf = loess(fill ~ x + y, data=data)
      df = data.frame(x = rep(dens$x, length(dens$y)),
                      y = rep(dens$y, each=length(dens$x)),
                      dens = c(dens$z))
      df$fill = predict(lsurf, newdata=df[c("x", "y")])
      df
    },
    required_aes = c("x", "y", "fill")
  )

  layer(
    stat = loess2d, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}

ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=hwy, fill=year)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=year)) + 
  stat_loess2d()

ggplot(mpg[mpg$class == "compact",], aes(x=displ, y=hwy, fill=year)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=year)) + 
  stat_loess2d()
```

[image: all loess2d] [image: one class loess2d]

However, when I try to facet the above, tiles are no longer shown:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=hwy, fill=year)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=year)) + 
  stat_loess2d() +
  facet_wrap(~ class)
```

[image: loess2d with facetting shows no tiles]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code gives me warnings that seem to be related to data sparsity.

Comment: I would argue that this is irrelevant here because the fit/plot works for individual facets (splitting the data and plotting individually) but not when using `facet_wrap(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

The main issue I see here actually lies beyond what you have done, & is related to how `geom_tile` handles tile creation across different facets, when the specific x / y axis values differ significantly. An [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18157975/8449629) demonstrated a similar phenomenon: `geom_tile` works fine with each facet's data on its own, but put them together, and the tiles shrink to match the smallest difference between different facets' values. This leaves vast amounts of white space in the plot layer, and usually gets progressively worse with every additional facet, until the tiles themselves become practically invisible.

To get around this, I would add a data processing step *after* the density / loess calculations for each facet, to standardize the range of x and y values across all facets.

Some elaboration in case you are not very familiar with the relationship between `compute_layer`, `compute_panel`, and `compute_group` (I certainly wasn't when I started messing around with ggproto objects...):

- Essentially, all `Stat*` objects have these three functions to bridge the gap between a given dataframe (`mpg` in this case), and what's received by the `Geom*` side of things.
- Of the three, `compute_layer` is the top-level function, and typically triggers `compute_panel` to calculate a separate dataframe for each facet / panel (the terminology used in exported functions is facet, but the underlying package code refers to the same as panel; I'm not sure why either). In turn, `compute_panel` triggers `compute_group` to calculate a separate dataframe for each group (as defined by the `group` / `colour` / `fill` / etc. aesthetic parameters).
- The results from `compute_group` are returned to `compute_panel` and combined into one dataframe. Likewise, `compute_layer` receives one dataframe from each facet's `compute_panel`, and combines them together again. The combined dataframe is then passed on to `Geom*` to draw.

*(Above is the generic set-up as defined in the top-level `Stat`. Other `Stat*` objects inheriting from `Stat` may override the behaviour in any of the steps. For example, `StatIdentity`'s `compute_layer` returns the original dataframe as-is, without triggering `compute_panel` / `compute_group` at all, because there is no need to do so for unchanged data.)*

For this use case, we can modify the code in `compute_layer`, after the results have been returned from `compute_panel` / `compute_group` and combined together, to interpolate values associated with each facet into common bins. Because common bins = nice large tiles without white space in between.

## Modification

Here's how I would have written the `loess2d` ggproto object, with an additional definition for `compute_layer`:

```
loess2d = ggproto("loess2d", Stat,
                  compute_group = function(data, scales) {
                    dens = MASS::kde2d(data$x, data$y)
                    lsurf = loess(fill ~ x + y, data=data)
                    df = data.frame(x = rep(dens$x, length(dens$y)),
                                    y = rep(dens$y, each=length(dens$x)),
                                    dens = c(dens$z))
                    df$fill = predict(lsurf, newdata=df[c("x", "y")])
                    df
                  },
                  compute_layer = function(self, data, params, layout) {
                    # no change from Stat$compute_layer in this chunk, except
                    # for liberal usage of `ggplot2:::` to utilise un-exported
                    # functions from the package
                    ggplot2:::check_required_aesthetics(self$required_aes, 
                                                        c(names(data), names(params)), 
                                                        ggplot2:::snake_class(self))
                    data <- remove_missing(data, params$na.rm, 
                                           c(self$required_aes, self$non_missing_aes), 
                                           ggplot2:::snake_class(self),
                                           finite = TRUE)
                    params <- params[intersect(names(params), self$parameters())]
                    args <- c(list(data = quote(data), scales = quote(scales)), params)
                    df <- plyr::ddply(data, "PANEL", function(data) {
                      scales <- layout$get_scales(data$PANEL[1])
                      tryCatch(do.call(self$compute_panel, args), 
                               error = function(e) {
                                 warning("Computation failed in `", ggplot2:::snake_class(self), 
                                         "()`:\n", e$message, call. = FALSE)
                                 data.frame()
                               })
                    })

                    # define common x/y grid range across all panels
                    # (length = 25 chosen to match the default value for n in MASS::kde2d)
                    x.range <- seq(min(df$x), max(df$x), length = 25)
                    y.range <- seq(min(df$y), max(df$y), length = 25)

                    # interpolate each panel's data to a common grid,
                    # with NA values for regions where each panel doesn't
                    # have data (this can be changed via the extrap
                    # parameter in akima::interp, but I think  
                    # extrapolating may create misleading visuals)
                    df <- df %>% 
                      tidyr::nest(-PANEL) %>%
                      mutate(data = purrr::map(data, 
                                               ~akima::interp(x = .x$x, y = .x$y, z = .x$fill,
                                                              xo = x.range, yo = y.range,
                                                              nx = 25, ny = 25) %>%
                                                 akima::interp2xyz(data.frame = TRUE) %>%
                                                 rename(fill = z))) %>%
                      tidyr::unnest()

                    return(df)
                  },
                  required_aes = c("x", "y", "fill")
)
```

Usage:

```
ggplot(mpg,
       aes(x=displ, y=hwy, fill=year)) + 
  stat_loess2d() +
  facet_wrap(~ class)
# this does trigger warnings (not errors) because some of the facets contain
# really very few observations. if we filter for facets with more rows of data
# in the original dataset, this wouldn't be an issue

ggplot(mpg %>% filter(!class %in% c("2seater", "minivan")),
       aes(x=displ, y=hwy, fill=year)) + 
  stat_loess2d() +
  facet_wrap(~ class)
# no warnings triggered
```

[image: results]